# Interquartile range to find out outlier & get perfect Standard deviation

Tags: statistics

I have one population dataset -

```
200, 330, 675, 999, 1200, 3000, 25000
```

For this dataset `IQR = 3000 - 330 = 2670`

Also we will get

```
lower limit = 330 - 1.5(2670) = -3675
Upper limit = 3000 + 1.5(3000 -330) = 7005
```

From above information **How do I find Outlier?**

As per the Tukey fences `[Q1 - 1.5(Q3 - Q1), Q3 + 1.5(Q3 - Q1)]` outside of these limit is outlier.

So I want to calculate standard deviation of above dataset. Then while calculating Standard Deviation, should I have to consider outlier or not.

Here we will get two cases -

1. Proper standard deviation (when outlier not consider) = 931.60
2. Wrong standard deviation (when outlier consider) = 8418.98

So what should I have to consider or is there any other way to get perfect Standard Deviation. As per data set **931.60** is perfect one.

Comment: You can  apply this definition of an outlier: A data point is an outlier if it is outside the range of $[Q_{1}-1.5IQR,Q_{4}+1.5IQR]$. Your calculation are right. Then 2$5,000$ is an outlier.

Comment: Minus lower limit is acceptable in rang ? Because data set which I have taken is price of product. Shall I consider it to 0 as lower limit.

Comment: First note that you and I used a specific and common definition of  an outlier. There are several other possible definition of outliers. But with this definition $25,000$ is an outlier. It doesn´t play a role that the price cannot be negative. But you can take 0 as an lower limit if the lower limit is smaller than 0.

Answer (score 1):

The rule using the IQR is often used with boxplots. Using R statistical
software, we obtain the following:

```
 x = c(200, 330, 675, 999, 1200, 3000, 25000)
 IQR(x)
 ## 1597.5
 sd(x)
 ## 9093.544
 boxplot(x, horizontal=T)
```

[image]

The vertical line at 200 is the smallest data value above the lower 'fence'; the lower
end of the box is at 502.5; the heavy line inside the box is
the median 999; the upper end of the box is at 2100; the
vertical line at the right end of the upper whisker is at 3000
(the largest data point below the upper fence); and the dot at the
far right is the outlier 25,000.

I got these numbers from `boxplot.stats` (output shown below
with slight editing):

```
 boxplot.stats(x)

 $stats  # lower fence, lower hinge, median, upper hinge, upper fence
 [1]  200.0  502.5  999.0 2100.0 3000.0

 $n
 [1] 7  # sample size

 ...

 $out  # list of outliers (here only one)
 [1] 25000
```

Various books and software may give different values for
the numbers at the ends of the box (lower and upper hinges,
or lower and upper quartiles). This also means that the IQR
can differ from one account to another.

The sample standard deviation is found as $S = \sqrt{\frac{\sum (X_i - \bar X)^2}{n-1}}.$ For a sample as highly skewed as this one, I would
not suppose you are asked to use $S$ to find outliers.

Note: If by the 'perfect' standard deviation, you mean the population
standard deviation $\sigma$, then one sometime says that
data values outside the interval $(\mu - 3\sigma, \mu + 3\sigma)$
is an outlier, where $\mu$ is the population mean. From the
information given, you have no way to know exact values of $\mu$ or
$\sigma.$ Maybe there is something missing from your question.

Addenda prompted by additional questions:

$S$ (computed from all the data) is a reasonably good estimate of σσ if the data are truly random sample from the population. The main issue is whether the outlier really 'represents' the population, or whether it is some sort of mistake (e.g., recording error, equipment failure, etc).

Example 1: The exponential distribution is a strongly right skewed and samples from it typically show many outliers in the right tail. I just simulated a sample of size 1000 from an exponential population with population mean and SD both 5. There were 27 outliers in the right tail. The sample SD of all 1000 observations was 4.70 (reasonably close to 5).Omitting the outliers, the sample SD was only 3.6.

Example 2: I simulated a sample of size 1000 from a normal dist'n with pop mean 100 and SD 10. Sample mean 100.3; sample SD 10.2. A few moderate outliers in each tail. I added an outrageous mistaken value of 2000, obviously an outlier. With this bogus observation included the sample SD is 60.9 (far from 10).

The overall lesson is not to discard 'outliers' without good
reason. Check for data input errors. Check lab notes for
indications of measurement difficulty or equipment failure.
There are no general rules.
The question whether to discard an outlier is frequently a
judgment call. Does the 'outlier' represent the target population
or not? In practice, never discard an observation without making
a note that you did so, and why. (And maybe show how analysis differs if outliers are left in.)

Comment: Thank you for response. The given data set represent to population. The my question is that, when I calculate S should I ignore outlier from data set and calculate S based on other data set members.

Comment: So what will be the best practice in such cases, if population contains false members.

Comment: Edited my previous comments into my Answer as 'addenda'. Plus an attempt to answer this most recent question. 'Best practice' is to make sure data are clean, then throw out outliers only for good reason, and admit you've done it. If this is a drill problem in an elementary book written by mathematicians who wouldn't know real data if they saw it, my guess is that you are being set up to discard the outlier before computing $S.$ If it is a more sophisticated data analysis course, my guess is you are expected to give a well-reasoned answer.

Comment: Yes I am looking for well reason answer. Thank you for response.